# How to undo rar archive extraction?

Tags: 14.04, extract, 7zip, rar

How to undo rar archive extraction? Incorrectly extracted with 7z utility, multiple errors, dirty extraction with "unsupported method".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove what was extracted with the `rm` command. Normally I would believe you need to `rm` a directory and all files of the extract will be inside that directory.

---

A tar file itself is not removed so you can always redo the extract. Though ... what you say here probably means you have a tar file that is not complete or not downloaded correctly.

To help more we need the actual command used and error notices.

Comment: The file is .rar,  I tried extract it with 7z by mistake, which don't support .rar archives. It clogged the whole `Downloads` folder with plenty of extracted files, so its very difficult to define what files was actually extracted among other files.

Comment: It will be a manual task though so I wish you luck and  have fun ;-)